# Spring boot: bean definition name duplicated

Tags: spring-boot, spring-ioc

I'm getting next message when my service starts:

> ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'estatRegistreServiceImpl' for bean class [cat.gencat.catsalut.hes.mpi.api.loader.service.EstatRegistreServiceImpl] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [cat.gencat.catsalut.hes.mpi.api.admin.service.impl.EstatRegistreServiceImpl]

> Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'estatRegistreServiceImpl' for bean class [cat.gencat.catsalut.hes.mpi.api.loader.service.EstatRegistreServiceImpl] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [cat.gencat.catsalut.hes.mpi.api.admin.service.impl.EstatRegistreServiceImpl]

Currently, I've created two packages containing my services:

```
src/main/java/cat/gencat/catsalut/hes/mpi/api/admin/service/
src/main/java/cat/gencat/catsalut/hes/mpi/api/loader/service/
```

src/main/java/cat/gencat/catsalut/hes/mpi/api/admin/service/

```
src/main/java/cat/gencat/catsalut/hes/mpi/api/admin/service/
├── EstatRegistreService.java
├── impl
    ├── EstatRegistreServiceImpl.java
```

And

```
src/main/java/cat/gencat/catsalut/hes/mpi/api/loader/service/
├── EstatRegistreService.java
├── impl
    ├── EstatRegistreServiceImpl.java
```

Both beans are registered using the same name: `estatRegistreServiceImpl`.

I know I've able to use `@Service` annotation setting a registration name. I don't want to mantain these string literals since I've a lot of service-like classes.

Is there any way to get it without using `@Service("service1") and` @Service("service2)`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can create a custom bean name generator. It will add full qualifier path to when registering bean.

Here I have implemented to ApplicationRunner interface just to illustrate the what is the bean names will be!

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(nameGenerator = YourMainApplication.CustomGenerator.class)
public class YourMainApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(YourMainApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(YourMainApplication.class);
    }

    public static class CustomGenerator extends AnnotationBeanNameGenerator {
        @Override
        public String generateBeanName(BeanDefinition definition, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
            return definition.getBeanClassName();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
        String[] allServiceBeansNames = context.getBeanNamesForAnnotation(Service.class);
        for(String beanName : allServiceBeansNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }
    }
}
```